# Parallelizing recursive function calls on each element of an array (with ForkJoinPool)

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, recursion, concurrency

Consider the following scenario:

```
public void processArray(int a, SomeType array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        recFunction(a, array[i]);
    }
}
private void recFunction(int a, SomeType element){
     ...
     recFunction(a + x, element);
     recFunction(a + y, element);
     ...
}
```

processArray invokes recFunction on each element of the array. How could I create a parrallel version of this programm using Java? Note that the array to be processed can be extremely large (up to 10,000 elements). My first thought was to use a ForkJoinPool but I definitely cannot create a RecursiveTask for each array element because that would create 10,000 new objects.

Also, I'll have to process different arrays and therefore will have to call processArray a couple of times. I would like to avoid creating new threads each time and use existing threads. Any ideas how I could implement that using a Executor or a ForkJoinPool?

Comment: Is it possible to split your array/s. For example create 4 Threads an each computes one half of an array? Or are the elements interdepentent? Is it really worthy to parallize this task? Also I think ForkJoinTask scales pretty much with ForkJoinPool. How many new Task would one Task create? (maybe post complete problem?)

Comment: A 10k array is too small to parallelise, 10m is a candidate. Then, follow the examples in the JavaDoc to decompose the array. When you get to the threshold, you call ProccessArray() on a segment of the large array and join the results up the chain.

Comment: @edharned: It could be worthy to parallize if the processing of one element takes much time.

Comment: @OP true. Then follow the decomposing examples in the JavaDoc or the Many, Many examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: The overhead for creating 10k `RecursiveTask` objects is surprisingly low, however, the other comments are valid: You would not go down to single elements (that is, you'd anyhow end with maybe 1000 tasks, each processing 10 elements or so), and whether the fact that the function is recursive is a reason to use a fork join pool is not clear from the description so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick sort example, not optimal by any means, but should give you a basis for comparison with the recursive version.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class ParallelSort {
    // default, Creates a ForkJoinPool with parallelism equal to Runtime.availableProcessors()
    private ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

    public void sort(int[] elements) {
        pool.invoke(new SortAction(elements, 0, elements.length-1));
    }

    public class SortAction extends RecursiveAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3060427288506544983L;

        final int[] elements;
        int low;
        int high;

        SortAction(int[] elements, int low, int high) {
            this.elements = elements;
            this.low = low;
            this.high = high;
        }

        protected void compute() {
            if (low < high) {
                int pivotIndex = (low + high) >>> 1;
                pivotIndex = partition(pivotIndex);

                invokeAll(new SortAction(elements, low, pivotIndex - 1),
                          new SortAction(elements, pivotIndex + 1, high));
            }
        }

        private int partition(int pivotIndex) {
            int pivotValue = elements[pivotIndex];

            swap(elements, pivotIndex, high);
            int storeIndex = low;

            for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
                if (elements[i] < pivotValue) {
                    swap(elements, i, storeIndex);
                    storeIndex++;
                }
            }

            swap(elements, storeIndex, high);
            return storeIndex;
        }

        private void swap(int[] elements, int i, int j) {
            if (i != j) {
                int temp = elements[i];
                elements[i] = elements[j];
                elements[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some quick notes:

- you don't *need* to declare the ForkJoinPool inside your sort class, I just did it here so the caller doesn't have to think about the pool.
- this kind of quicksort performs better if it falls back to a serial sort once the partition size is small-ish.  I didn't bother with that here.

This has no problem running on millions of elements.

Comment: You really should have mentioned the SOURCE of the above as well as a link to it, which appears to be http://ricardozuasti.com/2012/java-concurrency-examples-forkjoin-framework/

Comment: @javadba Quicksort is pretty much the same in all algorithm books (as are the ForkJoinPool examples).  Additionally note that site's example sorts on a List<T> which is incredibly bad if you pass a LinkedList in to it.

Comment: And, if you want to be pedantic, these were equally influential: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

(the author of your link obviously following the latter's pseudocode, btw, right down to the "storeIndex" name)